# Find previous DOM element jQuery using this

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some boxes set up with html and each box has a content div inside of it with a border right property.

The goal is when you hover over a box, the border right of the inner div disappears and the border of the previous box disappears as well.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box-content">
        <p>text text text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  padding 100px;
}

.box-content {
  height: 200px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(".box").hover(
        function() {
            jQuery(this).find(".box-content").css( "border-right", "none" );
            jQuery(this).find(".box .box-content").prev().css( "border-right", "none" );
        },
        function() {
            jQuery(this).find( ".box-content" ).css( "border-right", "1px solid black" );
            jQuery(this).find(".box .box-content").prev().css( "border-right", "black" );
        }
    );
```

I am close to getting it to work, I've successfully gotten the border to disappear when hovering but I can't get the previous box to remove its right border.

How can I fix this? I'm able to use a jQuery solution or a pure CSS solution.

[JS Fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vdjhjgsu/1/)

Comment: `.find(".box .box-content").prev()` reverse. remove `.box`, you'll already be on `.box`.

Comment: you are suggesting to just remove `.box`?

Comment: that plus reverse the two methods. Go to previous box, then it's child. not it's child, then previous

Comment: ah I know what you mean now, reverse it. so `.prev().find(".box-content").css`

Comment: could you post it as an answer and ill accept it?

Comment: shibi's covers it quite well

Comment: Thanks I wanted to give you points but ill give shibi the points. Thanks again sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already inside the current `.box` that you hover when you use `jQuery(this)`.

You need to remove the `.box` and to use prev right after the `jQuery(this)`

```
jQuery(".box").hover(
    function() {
        jQuery(this).find(".box-content").css( "border-right", "none" );
        jQuery(this).prev().find(".box-content").css( "border-right", "none" );
    },
    function() {
        jQuery(this).find( ".box-content" ).css( "border-right", "1px solid black" );
        jQuery(this).prev().find(".box-content").css( "border-right", "1px solid black" );
    }
);
```

This is how its should look like